# Is there any way how to add event to YUI calendar?

Tags: events, calendar, yui

I am using YUI calendar widget. (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/) Is there any way how to add/register event to date in this calendar?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YUI's Calendar provides `selectionChange` event. It might be able to help you wants. See also a example code and API docs.

- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/calendar-simple.html
- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/CalendarBase.html#event_selectionChange